# MDX Max, Average and StDev functions not giving correct results

Tags: sql-server, ssas, statistics, business-intelligence, mdx

I have a scenario where I have `Date` dimension and `Time` dimension along with some other dimensions. The time dimension contains only `Hours` since there was no need to save data at minute or second level.

A situation requires me to calculate `Average` of `Max` of value of certain hours of day. For instance, I need the `Max` of value between 01:00 to 04:00 hours and average of these maximum values in the given time period (01 January 2015 - 03 January 2015 in this example).

I am filtering `Date` and `Time` dimensions (along with other dimensions) as `Subselect` `From` clauses instead of using `Where`.

If the `Time` dimension members remain the same for each selected value of `Date` dimension, then `Max`, `Avg` and `StDev` give correct result, but if I have to exclude some hours from one of the `Date` dimension members, `Max` results in error, and `Avg` and `StDev` give incorrect values.

Please refer to the SQL code below to create the example I will be using in this question:

```
create database TestDateTimeDimensions
GO

USE [TestDateTimeDimensions]
GO

create table DimDate (
DateId int not null PRIMARY KEY,
Date [Date] not null
)


insert into DimDate
select 20150101, CONVERT(DATE, '2015-01-01')
UNION ALL
select 20150102, CONVERT(DATE, '2015-01-02')
UNION ALL
select 20150103, CONVERT(DATE, '2015-01-03')
UNION ALL
select 20150104, CONVERT(DATE, '2015-01-04')

create table DimTime(
TimeId int not null PRIMARY KEY,
[Time] Time not null
)

insert into DimTime
select 0, CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 1, CONVERT(TIME, '01:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 2, CONVERT(TIME, '02:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 3, CONVERT(TIME, '03:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 4, CONVERT(TIME, '04:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 5, CONVERT(TIME, '05:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 6, CONVERT(TIME, '06:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 7, CONVERT(TIME, '07:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 8, CONVERT(TIME, '08:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 9, CONVERT(TIME, '09:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 10, CONVERT(TIME, '10:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 11, CONVERT(TIME, '11:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 12, CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 13, CONVERT(TIME, '13:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 14, CONVERT(TIME, '14:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 15, CONVERT(TIME, '15:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 16, CONVERT(TIME, '16:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 17, CONVERT(TIME, '17:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 18, CONVERT(TIME, '18:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 19, CONVERT(TIME, '19:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 20, CONVERT(TIME, '20:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 21, CONVERT(TIME, '21:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 22, CONVERT(TIME, '22:00:00')
UNION ALL
select 23, CONVERT(TIME, '23:00:00')

CREATE TABLE Fact (
Id int identity not null PRIMARY KEY,
DateId int not null REFERENCES DimDate(DateId),
TimeId int not null REFERENCES DimTime(TimeId),
value int not null
)

insert into Fact

select DateId, TimeId, ROUND(RAND(CONVERT(varbinary, NEWID())) * 100, 2)
FROM DimDate, DimTime
```

The `MDX` query that works correctly is:

```
WITH
MEMBER MaxMember as MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value])
MEMBER AvgOfMax as Avg(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))
MEMBER StDevOfMax as StDev(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))

SET DateSet as EXISTING [Dim Date].[Date Id].[Date Id]
SET TimeSet as EXISTING [Dim Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]

select
{
    [Measures].[Value], MaxMember, AvgOfMax, StDevOfMax
}
on 0,
{
    DateSet * TimeSet
} on 1

FROM 
(
    SELECT ({[Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150101] : [Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150103]}, {[Dim Time].[Time Id].&[1] : [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[4]})
    on 0
    FROM [Test Date Time Dimensions]
)
```

It displays the result correctly as:

[image: Correct Result]

Note that the items included in Axis 1 are not used and the actual query returns only one row. They are just for this example.

The query that doesn't work as expected is:

```
WITH
MEMBER MaxMember as MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value])
MEMBER AvgOfMax as Avg(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))
MEMBER StDevOfMax as StDev(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))

SET DateSet as EXISTING [Dim Date].[Date Id].[Date Id]
SET TimeSet as EXISTING [Dim Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]

select
{
    [Measures].[Value], MaxMember, AvgOfMax, StDevOfMax
}
on 0

,
{
    DateSet * TimeSet
} on 1

FROM 
(
    SELECT {({[Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150101] : [Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150102]} * {[Dim Time].[Time Id].&[1] : [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[4]})
    , ([Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150103] * [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[3] : [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[4])}
    on 0
    FROM [Test Date Time Dimensions]
)
```

Here, I have excluded Hours `01:00` and '02:00`from Date`3 January 2015`. The maximum value (70) is at hour`01:00`of`3 January 2015`but is still being used to calculate Avg and`StDev`, and`Max` column is giving error, as shown in the image:

[image: Error]

Here Average and Standard Deviation are both incorrect.

Please help me finding a way to correctly calculate the results in this second case, and explain why Max is giving error and `Avg` and `StDev` functions still calculating including the Maximum value that is not included in the filtered `Subselect` clause.

A less than ideal workaround that I have come up with is to add a new `DateTime` Dimension that has both `Date` and `Time`, and use this `DateTime` dimension in the `Subselect` clause, and utilize the existing `Time` dimension to calculate `Max` and `Date` dimension to get Average and Standard Deviation, as in code below:

Create and fill the `DateTime` dimension:

```
create table DimDateTime
(
    DateTimeId int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date] Date not null,
    [Time] Time not null 
)

insert into DimDateTime

select ((DateId * 100) + TimeId) DateTimeId, DimDate.Date, DimTime.Time
from DimDate, DimTime

alter table Fact add DateTimeId int References DimDateTime(DateTimeId)

update Fact set DateTimeId = ((DateId * 100) + TimeId)
```

The `MDX` query returning correct result:

```
WITH
MEMBER MaxMember as MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value])
MEMBER AvgOfMax as Avg(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))
MEMBER StDevOfMax as StDev(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))

SET DateSet as NONEMPTY ([Dim Date].[Date Id].[Date Id])
SET TimeSet as NONEMPTY ([Dim Time].[Time Id].[Time Id])

select
{
    [Measures].[Value], MaxMember, AvgOfMax, StDevOfMax
}
on 0,
{
    NONEMPTY(DateSet * TimeSet)
} on 1

FROM 
(
    SELECT ({[Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010101] : [Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010104],
            [Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010201] : [Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010204],
            [Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010303] : [Dim Date Time].[Date Time Id].&[2015010304]})
    on 0
    FROM [Test Date Time Dimensions]
)
```

But I would prefer to avoid creating a new dimension, in addition to the existing two dimensions containing the same data. Secondly I want to avoid getting the data into the application and calculating the result in API methods. So the preference is to make `Max`, `Avg` and `StDev` functions to work correctly.

Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing it in MDX but to no avail, therefore I had to use the SSAS User Defined Function to calculate the Avg of Max. The set to calculate `Avg` (`DateSet`) across, set to calculate `Max` across (`TimeSet`) and a third set to containing the records to be excluded in `Max` operation, are passed as parameters to the UDF.

The basic code is like (presenting the coded Avg of Max functionality, excluding error checking):

```
public static class AvgOfMaxMethods
    {
        public static double AvgOfMax(Set maxAcrossSet, Set avgAcrossSet, Set setToExclude, Expression measureExpression)
        {
            var setToExcludeQueryable = setToExclude.Tuples.OfType<Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer.Tuple>();
            IList<double> maxMembers = new List<double>();
            foreach(var avgAcrossTuple in avgAcrossSet.Tuples)
            {
                var max = double.MinValue;
                foreach(var maxAcrossTuple in maxAcrossSet.Tuples)
                {
                    if (!setToExcludeQueryable.Any(tuple => tuple.Members[0].UniqueName.Equals(avgAcrossTuple.Members[0].UniqueName) && tuple.Members[1].UniqueName.Equals(maxAcrossTuple.Members[0].UniqueName)))
                    {
                        TupleBuilder tb = new TupleBuilder(avgAcrossTuple.Members[0]);
                        tb.Add(maxAcrossTuple.Members[0]);
                        var calculatedVal = measureExpression.Calculate(tb.ToTuple()).ToDouble();
                        max = calculatedVal > max ? calculatedVal : max;
                    }
                }
                if (!max.Equals(double.MinValue))
                {
                    maxMembers.Add(max);
                }
            }
            return maxMembers.Average();
        }
    }
```

An with this the query becomes (keeping the original `Max` and `StDev` for comparison):

```
WITH
MEMBER MaxMember as MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value])
MEMBER AvgOfMax as Avg(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))
MEMBER StDevOfMax as StDev(DateSet, MAX(TimeSet, [Measures].[Value]))
Member MaxFromUDF as UDFPoc.UDFPoc.AvgOfMaxMethods.AvgOfMax(TimeSet, DateSet, SetToExclude, [Measures].[Value])

SET DateSet as EXISTING [Dim Date].[Date Id].[Date Id]
SET TimeSet as EXISTING [Dim Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]
SET SetToExclude as {[Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150103] * [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[1] : [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[2]}

select
{
    [Measures].[Value], MaxMember, AvgOfMax, StDevOfMax, MaxFromUDF
}
on 0,
{
    DateSet * TimeSet
} on 1

FROM 
(
    SELECT ({[Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150101] : [Dim Date].[Date Id].&[20150103]}, {[Dim Time].[Time Id].&[1] : [Dim Time].[Time Id].&[4]})
    on 0
    FROM [Test Date Time Dimensions]
)
```

And the results look like (here tuples of the excluded set is highlighted in red):

[image]

As can be seen, the UDF excludes the members of each tuple in the `SettoExclude` set when calculating `Max` and `Average`. Now correct average considering the excluded set is being calculated, as can be seen in the image. Similarly `StDev` can be calculated in this manner.

See [this](http://www.infotoad.com/blog/post/2013/01/13/Creating-and-using-MDX-Stored-Procedures-ADOMDNET-Server-Programming.aspx) as a guide to create SSAS User Defined Functions.